Win 10: how to connect through a particular wifi adapter?
My Win-10 laptop has an internal wifi adapter and a USB wifi dongle connected. How do I  force it to connect through the dongle and not the internal adapter? The dongle has a high-gain antenna.

If you do not want to use a particular network adapter (Wi-Fi or otherwise), you can disable it. You can do so in Device Manager or the “Network Connections” view. Disabling an adapter will stick across reboots.
Unlike, say, uninstalling the device.
